# Repeat on an BehaviorSubject

Tags: rxjs

I want to reemit the last value of my observable at a fix interval, to I tried

```
obs.pipe(repeat({delay:1000})).subscribe(x => console.log('Emitted', x));
```

but it did not work. after looking into this, my observable is in fact a BehaviorSubject.

So my Question is Why does the 1st emits every second

```
of('Observable').pipe(repeat({ delay: 1000 })).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

but not the this?

```
var bs = new BehaviorSubject('BehaviorSubject');
bs.pipe(repeat({ delay: 1000 })).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

How to do it with my BehaviorSubject?

**Edit**

And I would also like to reset my timer when the subject emits a new value.

the solution I found is

```
var bs = new BehaviorSubject('BehaviorSubject');
bs.pipe(switchMap(x => timer(0,1000).pipe(map => () => x)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

but it feels ugly.

Comment: If you like to keep the repeat you could do something like this `bs.pipe(switchMap((x) => of(x).pipe(repeat({ delay: 1000 }))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive an observable from your `BehaviorSubject` that `switchMap`s to a `timer` that emits the received value.  Whenever the subject emits, the timer is reset and will emit the latest value:

```js
const bs = new BehaviorSubject('initial value');

const repeated = bs.pipe(
  switchMap(val => timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(() => val)
  ))
);
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74659233?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts) demo.

---

> So my Question is Why does the 1st emits every second, but not the this?

The reason your example code using `of` as the source works and not the code using the `BehaviorSubject` can be found in the documentation of the [`repeat`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/repeat) operator:

> Returns an Observable that will resubscribe to the source stream **when the source stream completes**.

The observable created using `of` completes after it emits the provided value, so it will resubscribe.  Since the `BehaviorSubject` was not completed, it will not resubscribe.

Comment: +1 for explaining why repeat was not wroking, i feel dumb for missing that, but your solution is exactly the workaround I found, and in the question.